# Im having trouble getting the correct response here, with this simple number input assignment

Tags: java, for-loop

this is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;
  public class Assignment3
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int numinput=0;
double suminput=0;
double lastinput=1;
double highest=0;
double lowest=0;
double firstinput=0;
int numextra=0;
  System.out.println("Please type in a number. Type 0 to quit.");
    firstinput=scan.nextDouble();

   if(firstinput==0)
    {
    System.out.println("You didn't type anything in.");
    return;
     }
    if(firstinput!=0)
    {
        numextra=1;
    }
    for(lastinput=1;lastinput != 0;numinput++)
    {

     System.out.println("Please type in a number. Type 0 to quit.");
    lastinput=scan.nextDouble();


    suminput=suminput+lastinput;
     if(lastinput > highest){
    highest = lastinput;
    }else if (lastinput < lowest){
    lowest=lastinput;

     }


     }
   suminput= suminput+firstinput;
   numinput=numinput+numextra;

   System.out.println("The sum of your inputs is: "+suminput);
     System.out.println("The total number of inputs you provided was:          " +numinput);
   System.out.println("The average of your inputs is: "+.    (suminput/numinput));
    System.out.println("The highest number you input was: "+highest);
   System.out.println("The lowest number you input was: "+lowest);

}
}
```

I should be getting the following return,
-6,
3,
-2,
-1,
-3,

but instead I am getting this,
-6,
4,
-1.5,
0,
-2

can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?
I tried to figure out how to not include the beginning value, if it is 0, but I had some trouble, and this is what I came up with, but its still not working properly, although it is closer to what the desired outcome then before.

Answer (score 0):

`numinput++` in for loop is incremented by one even when you enter `0` to exit, you should exclude that input from count. Or, simply remove the line `numinput=numinput+numextra`

**UPDATE** also when you compare double use `java.lang.Double.compare()`

Comment: that still doesn't give the correct output though, there is still something else wrong with the code

Comment: are you conidering `0` as a input or as a exit condition alone

Comment: As an exit condition alone. But if 0 is pressed first, then it displays a message that says you didn’t enter any numbers. But otherwise, it should not be counted for any of the counts, this is where I’m having problems

Comment: and what do you mean comparing doubles? Highest and lowest?

Comment: Also inside for loop you should not compare the values if the input is 0

Comment: How do I not compare the values if the input is 0?

Comment: sorry for all the questions, I'm just really a beginner when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: The code where you compare your input against highest and lowest should be within a if block having condition lastinput!=0

Comment: I tried that, but its still including 0 in the highest and lowest, its showing that 0 is the highest number instead of -1, when I input -1,-2,-3,0

Comment: Post your updated code and also the input given, expected output and actual output

Comment: where do I post the updated code? it won't let me put it in comments its toolong

Comment: Update your question

Comment: I just put it as an answer, I think you can see it now

Comment: You are initializing highest with value 0 and give only negative inputs, that&#39;s why highest is coming as 0, take your first non zero input as highest and lowest and then do further comparison against it, btw don&#39;t put question in answer section, remove it

Comment: what would be the exact code that I would need to insert? Im still having trouble

Comment: I finally figured it out, and completed it. Thanks for all your help!